# How do I find a directory in and store it into a variable, using a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to find the location of a specific directory, and then store that directory path into a variable within a Windows batch script.

I also want the command to return when it finds a match (to avoid searching the entire hard drive once the directory has already been found).

So far I've tried this on the command line:

```
dir c:\ /s /b /ad | find "DirectoryName"
```

The problem with this is that it searches the entire drive, even after a match is found. Plus, I still can't figure out how to store the result in a variable within a batch file. There should only be a single result.

Basically I need the equivilent of somehting like this on Linux/bash:

```
export DIRPATH=`find / -name "DirectoryName" -print -quit`
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: You need this change to the environment variable to be permanent, or only temporary for the duration of your batch file execution?

Comment: @Laf It only needs to be temporary for the batch file. Once I find this directory I need to copy in a few files.

Answer (score 1):

In batch you need `FOR /F` to get the output of a command.

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%p IN (`dir c:\ /s /b /ad ^| find "DirectoryName"`) DO (
  set "DIRPATH=%%p"
)
echo %DIRPATH%
```

As there are quotes in the find command you need the usebackq-option.
And it's necessary to escape the pipe character one time, as it should pipe the *dir* command, not the *for* command

Comment: I'm having some trouble with this. I get `DirectoryName: no such file or directory`, which seems odd since find is searching plain text piped from dir, correct?

Comment: It works for me, there was only a missspelling in `usebachq` instead of `usebackq`